# Data Annotations Extensions EqualTo and Compare not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, compare, data-annotations

I am using MVC3 and razaor view engine

I am trying to make sure that password and confirm password should match but this is not working for me. It just keeps on telling me "password" and "confirm password" do not match.

I have used "compare' and "equalto", both are resulting in the same error.

Business entity:

```
namespace Project.BusinessEntities
{
    public partial class RegisterPasswordUpdate
    {
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Validation:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using DataAnnotationsExtensions;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Project.Resources;


namespace Project.BusinessEntities
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(RegisterPasswordUpdate.RegisterPasswordUpdateMetaData))]
    public partial class RegisterPasswordUpdate
    {
        public class RegisterPasswordUpdateMetaData
        {
            [Required(ErrorMessage = ValidationMessageConstants.ResponseRequired)]
            [StringLength(16, MinimumLength = 8)]
            [RegularExpression(@"[A-Za-z0-9]*", ErrorMessage = ValidationMessageConstants.AlphaNumericOnly)]
            public string Password { get; set; }

            [Required(ErrorMessage = ValidationMessageConstants.ResponseRequired)]
            [StringLength(16, MinimumLength = 8, ErrorMessage = ValidationMessageConstants.MinimumLength)]
            [RegularExpression(@"[A-Za-z0-9]*", ErrorMessage = ValidationMessageConstants.AlphaNumericOnly)]
            [EqualTo("Password", ErrorMessage = ValidationMessageConstants.ConfirmPassword)]
            public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }


        }
    }
}
```

Use:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.PasswordUpdate.Password, new { maxlength = "16", size = "16" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.PasswordUpdate.Password)

@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.PasswordUpdate.ConfirmPassword, new { maxlength = "16", size = "16" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.PasswordUpdate.ConfirmPassword)
```

html:

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-length="The field Password must be a string with a minimum length of 8 and a maximum length of 16." data-val-length-max="16" data-val-length-min="8" data-val-regex="Only alphanumeric (A-Z a-z 0-9) values are allowed" data-val-regex-pattern="[A-Za-z0-9]*" data-val-required="Response required!" id="PasswordUpdate_Password" maxlength="16" name="PasswordUpdate.Password" size="16" type="text" value="" />

<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="PasswordUpdate.Password" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>

<input data-val="true" data-val-equalto="Password and confirm password do not match" data-val-equalto-other="*.Password" data-val-length="Minimum length not met" data-val-length-max="16" data-val-length-min="8" data-val-regex="Only alphanumeric (A-Z a-z 0-9) values are allowed" data-val-regex-pattern="[A-Za-z0-9]*" data-val-required="Response required!" id="PasswordUpdate_ConfirmPassword" maxlength="16" name="PasswordUpdate.ConfirmPassword" size="16" type="text" value="" />

<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="PasswordUpdate.ConfirmPassword" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
```

html ids on the page:

PasswordUpdate_Password
PasswordUpdate_ConfirmPassword

html names on the page:

PasswordUpdate.Password
PasswordUpdate.ConfirmPassword

What is missing here?

Comment: The problem here is 
data-val-equalto-other="*.Password".  

validation is applied to entity and not model. model has entity reference in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug and the following post helped fix it:
http://forums.asp.net/t/1716181.aspx/1

The problem lies in missing single quotes in theunobtrusive validation code. This line is incorrect:

```
 element = $(options.form).find(":input[name=" + fullOtherName + "]")[0];
```

and should be replace by

```
element = $(options.form).find(":input[name='" + fullOtherName + "']")[0];
```

Comment: Please don't just link, links may perish, leaving the question without an actual answer. (I've edited the answer to include the solution, which is now waiting for peer review...)